# Using wildcard with ifneq in Makefile

Tags: bash, makefile

Here's the piece of my Makefile:

```
MY_CONFIG ?= .config.yaml
...
.PHONY: %/foo
%/foo: %/bar.yaml
ifneq ($(wildcard $*/$(MY_CONFIG)),)
    $(info **FOUND CONFIG FILE** )
else
    $(info **DIDNT FIND CONFIG FILE** )
endif
```

I call this target like `make myfolder/foo` and there's `bar.yaml` and `.config.yaml` files under that `myfolder` directory. However, that ifneq doesn't seem to work and it always prints `DIDN'T FIND CONFIG FILE` so I'm wondering how can I fix my condition (`wildcard`?) in `ifneq` to make it find a config file.

File structure:

```
-- Makefile
-- myfolder
---- bar.yaml
---- .config.yaml
```

Comment: Note that you can't give patterns to `.PHONY`.  The statement `.PHONY: %/foo` says that the literal filename `%/foo` is phony which is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that this kind of statement:

```
ifneq (...)
  $(info ... )
else
  $(info ... )
endif
```

is in Make syntax. It is not really part of the rule. Make will evaluate it before executing any rule. In this case:

```
ifneq ($(wildcard $*/$(MY_CONFIG)),)
  ...
```

before Make matches the pattern rule to anything, `$*` has no value and expands to nothing, so unless you have a config file in your root directory, the search will always come up negative.

There are a couple of ways to get the result you want. The simplest is probably to divide the rule into two rules:

```
.PHONY: %/foo
%/foo: %/bar.yaml %/$(MY_CONFIG)
    @echo **FOUND CONFIG FILE**

%/foo: %/bar.yaml
    @echo **DIDNT FIND CONFIG FILE**
```

Alternatively, you could put a shell conditional inside the rule, in the syntax of the shell you use.